# Websphere 7 application needs to be deployed more than once to work on SunOS

Tags: websphere, websphere-7, sunos

I have an ear file for my work, when installing the ear file on on WAS7 / SunOS it gets installed successfully and when trying to access the app i get a blank page, after reinstalling the app 2-3 times the application works.

tested the same ear file on WAS7 / AIX and it works just fine.

WAS version is 7.0.0.15

Comment: When you try to access the page, has the app finished starting up?

Comment: yes, it is started successfully. Server logs mention no problem and the login page just appears empty.